# Cannot install any software in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, latex, ubuntu-14.04, dpkg

Initially, I had a very little problem. While executing a latex file, I got an error similar to

```
 \newtx package not found.
```

So, I decided to update latex. I followed the thread in the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/794671/upgrading-tex-live-from-2015-to-2016-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts and did the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2016
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

It did not install correctly. Shortly afterward, I start getting the error message

```
New software cannot be installed as there is a problem in the currently installed program.
```

I tried few things to fix the problem. e.g. I followed the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/474646/cant-install-software-can-i-fix-missing-dpkg and did

```
sudo -i
mkdir /tmp/dpkg
cd /tmp/dpkg
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb
ar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz
tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

The following error message is displayed after the final command

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
latex-beamer : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
prosper : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
skype :   Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
texlive : Depends: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2016) but    2013.20140215-1 is to be installed
          Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2016) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2016) but it is not going to be installed
texlive-base : Depends: luatex (>= 0.70.1)
          Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
texlive-fonts-recommended-doc : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016) but 2013.20140215-1 is to be installed
         Depends: tex-common (>= 6) but 4.04 is to be installed
texlive-latex-extra : Depends: luatex
         Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
texlive-latex-extra-doc : Depends: tex-common (>= 6) but 4.04 is to be installed
         Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016) but 2013.20140215-1 is to be installed
texlive-latex-recommended : Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
texlive-luatex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: luatex (>= 0.70.1)
texlive-pictures : Depends: luatex
         Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-generic-recommended (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
tipa : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: texlive-base-bin
wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

with the following error message

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (127)
```

My system has a 64 bit corei5 processor and OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I cannot even upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04. What is the solution to get out of this problem? Now, it is also saying that latex is not installed so that my work on latex is also halted.

Comment: You messed up with sources.list file.Reset it and it will be like begining keep internet connection ready to follow my solution@Himangshu Paul

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal and type

```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If it doesn't help then do this

```
  sudo apt autoremove <packagename>
```

If this doesn't help then you
Need an internet connection.Type in terminal

```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!

```
 sudo apt-get install ____packagename_____
```

Comment: I followed every step you suggested but the unmet dependencies persist. I found the following error--apt autoremove is said to be an incorrect command. When I do revert, all the ticks are restored automatically.

Comment: sudo dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: symbol lookup error: dpkg: undefined symbol: setexecfilecon

Comment: sudo apt autoremove texlive
E: Invalid operation autoremove

Comment: Did it work @Himangshu Paul...dpkg undefined symbol is strange! Seems like system crashed.. Everything should be reset once you revert and do sudo update.. Did u do sudo update after revert?

Comment: @HimangshuPaul Actually m on mac nowdays so i forgot which one to click..when you tick all the items you should click revert i guess if not try again opening software properties gtk and see if all are checked if u press close directly.. This is only for restoring sources.list then you need update to run..

Comment: Yes I did sudo update. Seems like reinstalling OS is the only option.

Comment: @HimangshuPaul don't press revert..did u do so?....btw i dont use latex tool it consumes my 3gb space...i use overleaf.com try it

Comment: The first time, I did. The next time I ticked everything in the ubuntu software tab. I unticked the repository that I installed in the other software tab and then press close (not revert). Then I updated. It asked to install 103 Mb of data but could not do it and showed the same error message. I think I will send you the sources.list file a few hours later. I am away from my machine at the moment.

Comment: @HimangshuPaul `sudo apt-get --purge --auto-remove packagename` last try else `dpkg --purge --force-depends application`

Comment: When I restarted computer yesterday, GUI was gone and I could only boot on tty. dpkg got corrupted. I tried to repair it by Ubuntu livecd but did not work. Finally, I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @HimangshuPaul hmmm. Such thing happens. Next time you install anything.don't interrupt thr installation till it completes :)